# uncheck a checkbox in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a list of checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="servicesModel" value={{item.name}} id={{item.name}} ng-click="toggleSelection(item.name)"/>
```

and I want to deselect the selected checkbox

```
$scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(id) {
window.alert("You can't select this !");
//deselect the selected checkbox
}
```

Every thing is working fine but I can't found how I could deselect the selected one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the model in and assign it `false`

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="servicesModel" value={{item.name}} id={{item.name}} ng-click="toggleSelection(item.name, servicesModel)"/>

$scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(id, model) {
    window.alert("You can't select this !");
    //deselect the selected checkbox
    model = false; //set
}
```

Comment: maybe mode.id= false ? but even like this it don't works

Answer (score 0):

Update the controller with angular $event as:

```
  $scope.toggleSelection = function ($event, item) {
      var checkbox = $event.target;
      var action = (checkbox.checked ? 'add' : 'remove');
      $scope.updateToggleSelection(action, item);
  };

  $scope.updateToggleSelection(action, item) {
    if(action =='add') {
       item = true;
     }  

    if(action == 'remove') {
     item = false;
     }
 }
```

And in the html as:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="servicesModel" value={{item.name}} id={{item.name}} ng-click="toggleSelection($event, item.name)"/>
```